# Convert float64 column to datetime pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have the following `pandas DataFrame` column `dfA['TradeDate']`:

```
0     20100329.0
1     20100328.0
2     20100329.0
...
```

and I wish to transform it to a datetime.

Based on another tread on SO, I convert it first to a string and then apply the `strptime` function.

```
dfA['TradeDate'] = datetime.datetime.strptime( dfA['TradeDate'].astype('int').to_string() ,'%Y%m%d')
```

However this returns the error that my format is incorrect (`ValueError`).

An issue that I spotted is that the column is not properly to string, but to an object.

When I try:

```
dfA['TradeDate'] = datetime.datetime.strptime( dfA['TradeDate'].astype(int).astype(str),'%Y%m%d')
```

It returns: must be a Str and not Series.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['TradeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TradeDate'], format='%Y%m%d.0')
print (df)
   TradeDate
0 2010-03-29
1 2010-03-28
2 2010-03-29
```

But if some bad values, add `errors='coerce'` for replace them to `NaT`

```
print (df)
    TradeDate
0  20100329.0
1  20100328.0
2  20100329.0
3  20153030.0
4         yyy

df['TradeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TradeDate'], format='%Y%m%d.0', errors='coerce')
print (df)
   TradeDate
0 2010-03-29
1 2010-03-28
2 2010-03-29
3        NaT
4        NaT
```

Comment: It says: DataFrame has no attribute to_datetime??

Comment: maybe typo `pd.to_datetime` not `df.to_datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_datetime` with a custom format on a string representation of the values:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([20100329.0, 20100328.0, 20100329.0]).astype(str), format='%Y%m%d.0')
```

Comment: It says: DataFrame has no attribute to_datetime

Comment: `pd` is `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Maybe you have created a dataframe with the name `pd`, which shadows the actual pandas module?

Answer (score 0):

`strptime` function works on a single value, not on series. You need to apply that function to each element of the column

try `pandas.to_datetime` method

eg

```
dfA = pandas.DataFrame({"TradeDate" : [20100329.0,20100328.0]})
pandas.to_datetime(dfA['TradeDate'], format = "%Y%m%d")
```

or

```
dfA['TradeDate'].astype(int).astype(str)\ 
    .apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt you tried to convert it to string and then pass to `strptime`, which resulted in `ValueError`. This happens because `dfA['TradeDate'].astype('int').to_string()` creates a single string containing **all** dates as well as their row numbers. You can change this to

```
dates = dfA['TradeDate'].astype('int').to_string(index=False).split()
dates
[u'20100329.0', u'20100328.0', u'20100329.0']
```

to get a list of dates. Then use [python list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to convert each element to *datetime*:

```
dfA['TradeDate'] = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d.0') for x in dates]
```